# How SWT browser work internally, does it call native browser or it uses OS libraries?

Tags: java, swt

How SWT browser works internally? does it call native browser or it uses OS libraries?

Kindly explain internal working of swt browsers or share some free documentations

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Eclipse Foundation](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-browser-widget/browser.html) - "The Browser widget binds to a suitable native HTML rendering engine for the platform it is running on (Internet Explorer on Windows, Mozilla on Linux, Safari on the Mac"

Comment: what If, we un install all the browsers will it work?

Comment: It is impossible to completely uninstall internet explorer from windows and safari from mac. So you if you want to test this you could uninstall firefox from a linux machine, I would expect an exception to be thrown.

Comment: SWT Dropped support for mozilla some time ago. SWT depends on webkit2 libraries for the browser to work. Need to install them separately on linux. In case of Mac Safari provides webkit libraries. In case of Windows SWT does have experimental support for edge browser using WebView2.

Answer (score 0):

The open source SWT browser Equo Chromium (https://github.com/equoplatform/chromium-swt) does not rely on native browsers (Internet Explorer on Windows, WebKit on macOS, and WebKitGTK+ or Mozilla/XULRunner on Linux). Instead, it binds to Chromium. Then you will have the same rendering experience across all platforms and you won't have to install any external libraries.